# Break from Python async for

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have a situation where I want to break from an async for loop. I managed to reduce the issue to the application below. I expect to enter the 'finally' section of the context manager when breaking from the loop in main. In other words, the expected result is

> try
>
> 456
>
> finally
>
> done

but what I get is

> try
>
> 456
>
> done
>
> finally

and then an exception when the application closes.

Here is the code

```
import asyncio
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager

@asynccontextmanager
async def receiving():
    try:
        print('try')
        yield 123
    finally:
        print('finally')

async def request_all():
    async with receiving():
        yield 456

async def main():
    async for r in request_all():
        print(r)
        break
    print('done')

asyncio.run(main())
```

I found [this](https://bugs.python.org/issue33786) bug report that seems similar, but as far as I can tell it has been resolved before 3.8. I tested my issue on 3.8.2 and 3.9.6

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can see how this behaviour is confusing, but I don't think it's a bug. If you bypass the exhaustion of the async Iterator with `break`, you never leave the `async with` in `request_all`, so the `finally`-block will not get executed until the event loop finishes. This has the advantage that you *could* exhaust the generator at a later point.

If you are sure, you don't need your generator anymore, you could close the async_generator instead of `break`ing to get your expected behaviour:

```py
import asyncio
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager

@asynccontextmanager
async def receiving():
    try:
        print('try')
        yield 123
    finally:
        print('finally')

async def request_all():
    async with receiving():
        yield 456

async def main():
    gen = request_all()
    async for r in gen:
        print(r)
        await gen.aclose() #instead of break
    print('done')

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Thanks! It's not very intuitive if you ask me, but at least it's not a bug. Solution works very well

Comment: Disclaimer: This code is to demonstrate how the context manager works. Please do not use it in production code as is :-)

Comment: Just a word of caution: remember that other than with `break`, `gen.aclose()` will not exit the `for`-loop immediately and code after it will be executed on the last iteration.

Comment: You should use a "`with aclosing(gen)` context manager. Keep the `break`.

`aclosing` is included in `contextlib` starting with py3.10, or the `async_generator` module from pypi.